# AngularJS Filter Array Based On Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array such as

```
$scope.myList = 
[
 ["one","two","three"],
 ["a","b","c"],
 ["one","two","three"]
]
```

And now I want to use ng-repeat to list out the third index with a filter.

```
<select >
    <option ng-repeat="item in myList| filter:item[2]:'text_here'">
         {{item[2]}} 
    </option>
</select><br/>
```

What would I do to filter the 3nd element of each array and apply an appropriate filter? I'm pretty sure my answer above is wrong.

Comment: what about `item in myList[scopeVar]` ..change index in controller using `$scope.scopeVar=2`

Comment: Read the docs on select. You may have problems creating it this way. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: I'm confused at what your trying to get your output to look like. 
do you mean you want to see `three, c, three`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well assuming you want your output to be `three,c,three` then you don't need a filter. You just need to change your ng-repeat to an ng-options, via http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

```
<select ng-options="item[2] as item[2] for item in myList"></select>
```

If you're only trying to list out the indexes of the third array in `$scope.myList` then you'd do this

```
<select ng-options="item as item for item in myList[2]"></select>
```